# How to make "Disable Developer Mode" disable in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I've installed a chrome extension by unpacking it, (It was not downloaded from Chrome Store) for which I had to select the option **Developer Mode**

Now every time the browser is opened, a pop up comes telling me to disable developer mode if I'm not a developer as it could harm my PC.

There were two buttons <kbd>Disable</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and I'm fed up clicking <kbd>cancel</kbd> every time. I know what I've installed and it definitely isn't sort of malware.

So, how can I disable this popup?

Comment: goto `chrome://extensions/` & untick the checkbox

Comment: It's already unticked @Sathya

Comment: Hi Amit, can you update the chrome version. This problem might happen if the Chrome is older then 34.0.XXX. If possible upgrade your chrome using "https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/thankyou.html?extra=devchannel&statcb=1&installdataindex=defaultbrowser" and check whether the issue resolved.

Comment: @vembutech no, it doesn't seem to be the problem. My Chrome version is Version 39.0.2171.95 m