# How to remove the alert Disable developer mode in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

I use my custom unpacked Chrome extension and I don't want to upload it to the Chrome Web Store. But every time when I open the Chrome browser I get the alert **"Disable developer mode extensions"**. How to remove this alert at all in Chrome v47.0.2526.106? I don't find it in the `resources.pak` file. Which file is the alert in?

Unfortunately, there is no answer by the link [How to make "Disable Developer Mode" disable in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/854907/how-to-make-disable-developer-mode-disable-in-google-chrome)

Comment: [How to hack chrome.dll to get rid of the "disable developer mode extensions" pop up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30361260)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217653/chrome-extension-warning-tutorial-for-unpacked-extension-on-windows seems related, and unfortunately there still isn't a good answer.